# Delete photos by clicking on it

Tags: javascript

I have a function that adds photos to the page. She can add multiple photos. How to make it so that by clicking on a photo, it was the one that was clicked to be deleted? Tell me please.

```js
function handleFileSelect(evt) {
  var files = evt.target.files; // FileList object

  // Loop through the FileList and render image files as thumbnails.
  for (var i = 0, f; f = files[i]; i++) {

    // Only process image files.
    if (!f.type.match('image.*')) {
      continue;
    }

    var reader = new FileReader();

    // Closure to capture the file information.
    reader.onload = (function(theFile) {
      return function(e) {
        // Render thumbnail.
        var span = document.createElement('span');
        span.innerHTML = ['<img class="thumb" src="', e.target.result,
          '" title="', escape(theFile.name), '"/>'
        ].join('');
        document.getElementById('list').insertBefore(span, null);
      };
    })(f);

    // Read in the image file as a data URL.
    reader.readAsDataURL(f);
  }
}

document.getElementById('files').addEventListener('change', handleFileSelect, false);
```

```css
.thumb {
  height: 75px;
  border: 1px solid #000;
  margin: 10px 5px 0 0;
}
```

```html
<input type="file" id="files" name="files[]" multiple />
<output id="list"></output>
```

Comment: Do something like $('.list').on('click', 'img.thumb', function(){ var theImageElement = this; });

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Does this satisfy your goal?

```js
function handleFileSelect(evt) {
  var files = evt.target.files; // FileList object

  // Loop through the FileList and render image files as thumbnails.
  for (var i = 0, f; f = files[i]; i++) {

    // Only process image files.
    if (!f.type.match('image.*')) {
      continue;
    }

    var reader = new FileReader();

    // Closure to capture the file information.
    reader.onload = (function(theFile) {
      return function(e) {
        // Render thumbnail.
        var span = document.createElement('span');
        span.innerHTML = ['<img class="thumb" src="', e.target.result,
          '" title="', escape(theFile.name), '"/>'
        ].join('');
        document.getElementById('list').insertBefore(span, null);
      };
    })(f);

    // Read in the image file as a data URL.
    reader.readAsDataURL(f);
  }
}

document.getElementById('files').addEventListener('change', handleFileSelect, false);

// I added this line
document.getElementById('list').addEventListener('click', (evt) => {
   evt.target.parentNode.removeChild(evt.target);
});
```

```css
.thumb {
  height: 75px;
  border: 1px solid #000;
  margin: 10px 5px 0 0;
}
```

```html
<input type="file" id="files" name="files[]" multiple />
<output id="list"></output>
```